# Graphically viewing CVS repository

Tags: cvs

I want to know that is there any nice tool which you would like to recommend for viewing the CVS repository *graphically*? Tags, branches, versions, merges etc.

**EDIT:**
A freeware will really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WinCvs](http://www.wincvs.org/shots.html) (and its mac and linux equivalents) can do this.

[image]
<sub>(source: [wincvs.org](http://www.wincvs.org/gcvs_graph.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

For SVN and Git I use SmartSVN and SmartGit. I really like them. Their [SmartCVS](http://www.syntevo.com/smartcvs/index.html) looks quite good. Check it out.

Comment: SmartCVS looks amazing ! Is it free? They seem to be allowing for a download.

Comment: Checked further.. they are providing a 31 day trial only :-(

Comment: You can continue using it after the 31 day trial. That's what I did with SmartSVN. It just disables the Professional features after 31 days. See http://www.syntevo.com/smartcvs/comparison.html for details. Note that the feature you asked for, the graphical log, is available in the free version.

Answer (score 1):

I find [tortoise cvs](http://www.tortoisecvs.org/) to be a great tool. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

[TkCVS](http://tkcvs.sourceforge.net/) is old, but if you are on Unix/Linux, it mighty even be installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, you can install de plugin
https://github.com/angvoz/net.sf.versiontree#version-tree-plugin-for-cvs

If not, WinCVS is very good too.